# Problema ao manipular arquivos de texto com o python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da forca, e para isso, estou pegando listas de palavras e colocando em arquivos no formato *.txt* para o Python utilizar no jogo.

Ao pegar uma lista de nomes de pessoas, tem uns que vem com parênteses depois do nome, e dentre estes, mais alguns com sinal de igual entre os parênteses, por exemplo:

> Ana Beatriz ( = )

Isso é devido o site de onde eu copiei os nomes. Ele tinha algumas indicações, e não dava pra copiar sem elas virem juntas.

Então, criei um código para o Python remover esses caracteres indesejados pra mim:

```py
entrada = open('Pessoas2.txt', 'r') # Cópia da lista de nomes que tenho
saida = open('Pessoas3.txt', 'w')   # Local onde as linhas editadas serão escritas

for linha in entrada:
    l = entrada.readline()
    l = l.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('=', '')
    l = l.rstrip()
    saida.write(l)

entrada.close()
saida.close()
```

Estava aparentemente tudo bem, o código funciona. Só que ele retira mais coisas do que eu quero. A minha lista original tem *200* nomes, e o novo arquivo contém apenas *100* nomes, ou seja, ele simplesmente apaga nomes, e eu não sei o porquê. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a linha está sendo lida a partir da variável `entrada`, o correto seria obtê-la a partir da variável `linha`. O seu código deve ficar assim:

```py
entrada = open('Pessoas2.txt', 'r')
saida = open('Pessoas3.txt', 'w')

for linha in entrada:
    l = linha.rstrip()
    # substituindo o ")" por um nova linha
    l = l.replace('(', '').replace(')', '\n').replace('=', '') 

    saida.write(l)
entrada.close()
saida.close()
```

Uma outra forma de fazer essa substituição é usar o método [`traslate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) ao invés do [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```py
with open('Pessoas2.txt') as entrada, open('Pessoas3.txt', 'w') as saida:
    for linha in entrada:
        linha = linha.rstrip()
        linha = linha.translate({ ord('('): '', ord('='): '', ord(')'): '\n' })
        saida.write(linha)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo aqui. Só fiz uma modificação, porque ele não estava quebrando as linhas em nomes que não tinham esses caracteres que eu queria remover. Então, no lugar de substituir o `')'` pelo `\n`, eu deixei como estava e adicionei um `saida.write('\n')` no final do loop.